# Custom variable scope with User Controls (Windows Forms) - multiple instance problem

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have created a user control for Windows forms that is a custom date/time control. The value of the date/time is displayed in a textbox. I created a public Property called DTValue backed by a private variable which is the value of the control.

The control works fine, but if I add more than one instance of the control to a form then it seems that when I change the DTValue for one coontrol, it also changes the other control.

How do I make the DTValue property specific to each instance of the user control?

Thanks for any advice.

```
'Properties
Private _DTValue As DateTime
Public Property DTValue As DateTime
    Get
        Return _DTValue
    End Get
    Set(value As DateTime)
        'We eliminate the seconds component of the DateTime variable
        _DTValue = value.Date.AddHours(value.Hour).AddMinutes(value.Minute)
        If SelectorVisible Then
            RefreshSelector()
        End If
        DTTextbox.Text = Format(_DTValue, DTFormat)
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: If you have *something* static (`Shared`) there, then un-Share it.

Comment: This is unrelated to your issue but we're not writing VB6 code so let's use `DTTextbox.Text = _DTValue.ToString(DTFormat)`.

Comment: I checked and there is nothing shared, except some auto generated code defining MySettings. There are no static variables. All variables, subs and functions are private.

Comment: Thanks for the update on Format - I changed it